# React router cannot GET any specified routes, except the root /

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Here's my App.jsx that's first mounted to the DOM:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home.jsx';
import Representatives from './Representatives.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: ''};
}

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/representatives" component={Representatives} />
                </Switch>
            </div> 
        </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

And here's the representative's component:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Representatives extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          Hello World!
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It looks exactly like examples I've seen and my webpack config looks like other's I've seen in similar posts. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at 4+ hours wracking my brain

Here's my webpack config:

```html
const path = require('path');

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './public/');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, 'index.jsx'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { "presets": [
            "@babel/env",
            "@babel/react"
        ] }
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I added the historyApiFallback: true, and publicPath: '/'
as recommended by another post here.

Here is the index.js:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Just to validate - if you swap the positions of your <Div> and <Switch> tags does that allow you to render your Representatives component? Or get rid of the Switch tags all together(should have the same result)..

Comment: Just tried removing them and switching them also, but solutions didn't change the behavior unfortunately. It has to be an issue with the server right?

Comment: If it's returning your Home, i wouldn't think it'd be a server issue. Do you have any console errors? Can you post your index.js file?

Comment: Just posted. Seriously thanks for your help. I've been trying to solve it by myself forever to no avail. No errors from webpack or the server, in the JS console I do have: "checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route (created by App)
    in App"

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your Representative's component. Can you post it? Or try changing the import to {Representatives}

Comment: Here's the representatives comp: https://pastebin.com/pizxTSWq

Comment: I'm not too sure... hopefully someone smarter than me can chime in here. I have a feeling it's something super obvious. If you remove your home route altogether, and just set it to your Representatives route, does it render?

Comment: It doesn't! So it has to be something to do with that component - thanks for being my rubber duck at least I have an inkling of where to look now

Comment: Try adding 404 route just to check if it works.   <Route exact component={Home} />. Put URL as /dsfdsfds (random value). If it works then issue with Representatives component.

Comment: Nope, still got a could not get error :(

Comment: When I put the representatives component on the default '/' route it displays properly though.